# MobileFirst OAuth Logout, cached OAuth indentity

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

This is a follow-on to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253465/mobilefirst-oauth-and-logout) about MobileFirst OAuth. The question being that a call to WL.Client.logout("SomeRealm") does not remove the OAuth token for that Realm/Scope and hence calls resources protected by OAuth still succeed.

The answer to which quotes the InfoCentre as requiring a call to

```
 obtainAuthorizationHeaderForScope
```

With the implication that this will clear the token. My experiments seem to indicate that this does not work as expected. First I am working with the JavaScript API and find this

```
 WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAuthorizationHeader("SomeRealm")
```

as the corresponding function. However this function seems to result in a call to

```
 http://myHost:10080/MyProject/authorization/v1/authorization
```

that it turn triggers the challenge handler, that is, it attempts to re-enter the specified Realm. I don't see any WL API to destroy the OAuth token. All I can think of is to call a programatic equivalent of

```
 localStorage.removeItem("com.worklight.oauth.idtoken")
```

Or put some kluges into my Challenge Handler. Have I missed something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logout is completed by calling

```
 WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAuthorizationHeader(); // no parameters
```

My error was in thinking we could selectively be removed from a single Realm, instead we in effect remove our entire OAuth token.

Comment: This worked for me too!. After `WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAuthorizationHeader()` success I can call again `WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAuthorizationHeader("SomeRealm");` so the login form will be shown again