# WL.Client.Logout not calling its onSuccess or onFailure callbacks?

Tags: logout, ibm-mobilefirst

Using Mobilefirst Platform 7.1,

I have noticed that logout function has stopped working. I have a browser web app which has a logout button which triggers:

```
WL.Client.logout("MyAuthenticatorRealm", {
    onSuccess: function(res) {
        console.log("success server logout"); // Never called :(
        WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAuthorizationHeader().then (
           function(header) {
               // I would reload the app here, 
           },
           function(error) {
               ...
           });
    },
    onFailure: function(res) {
        console.log("failure server logout"); // Never called :(
    }
});
```

But callbacks are never called. 
I have checked the [sample code](https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/CustomAuth) from this [tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/authentication-security/custom-authentication/custom-authentication-hybrid-applications/) and I can see the same thing happening too.

Is there something specific I need to add in 7.1? This used to work in 7.0

**EDIT 2015/08/31**

There is nothing in the server logs. The client web app seem to be doing a request to `authorization/v1/authorization?client_id=XYZ&scope=-MyAuthenticatorRealm&isAjaxRequest=true&x=0.07530371774919331` which returns 200 success.

[image]

**EDIT 2013/09/17**

With the new version (7.1.0.00.20150913-2345) the callback is called! However now I get an exception:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: WLAuthorizationManager is not defined

Is this the correct way to do the logout for the latest version? I am trying the "Desktop Browser"

[image]

Comment: Where are you testing it?

Comment: I am testing in the localhost. (Is that what you mean?)

Comment: I mean whether you're testing in preview or device. And also if you're getting anything in the logs.

Comment: Sorry I think my explanation was not good. My app is a desktop app. It only runs in the browser.

Comment: If you download sample https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/CustomAuth and import it into your eclipse workspace you can see the same result :(

Comment: Besides the callbacks not being called, is the application actually logged out? Meaning if you refresh the page are you still logged in? - Also, you mentioned this is a desktop app. Are you testing in the "common" preview or as a desktop app?

Comment: @NathanH The application is actually logged out. If I refresh the page and try to access a protected resource the login form appears. Also I am testing the "common" because the "desktop" stuff is broken. (That is another problem, endpoints have an incorrect prefix so everything ends up in error. A colleague reported that some days ago I think)

Comment: Ok then this is related to a known issue: logout in common preview does not work as expected. I'm looking into that for a fix as soon as possible.

Comment: I really appreciate you help @NathanH .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known issue currently in MobileFirst Platform 7.1

APAR PI47591 WL.CLIENT.LOGOUT DOES NOT WORK IN HYBRID PREVIEW

You can open a PMR with IBM to share your interest for this fix, and get updated.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, we will open an PMR

Comment: I have updated my question for the latest release: 7.1.0.00.20150913-2345 . I still don't know how to logout properly :(

Comment: I don't think a fix was released for this yet. Open a PMR and ask to be notified when the above APAR is fixed

Comment: We opened a PMR and were notified recently. I am trying not the common preview but the "Desktop Browser". (I have edited the question and added a picture)

Comment: Why are you using WLAuthorizationManager? What were you trying to achieve? I don't think this class exists in Desktop Browser

Comment: I just want to logout. Is `WL.Client.logout` enough? I read in other thread that I need to use WLAuthorizationManager after that. Is this true? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30276754/mobilefirst-oauth-logout-cached-oauth-indentity

Comment: Logout is enough. The code you wrote is a workaround for an issue specific to OAuth in 7.0. It should not be relevant to your case as you use neither OAuth nor 7.0

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much!