# logout for Java adapters

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I know logout desn't work for Java adapter in Worklight 7.0, and found that it still doesn't work in Worklight 7.1. Is there any good work-around to discard an authenticated session?

Comment: Doesn't work WHERE? When asking question you are supposed to actually provide information so we could help you. Please review the Stack Overflow help section to learn how to ask questions.

Comment: Are you in the browser or on device? If browser, please refresh the page after logout and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not explaining what you're doing nor where you're doing it as well as did not provide a single line of code (you can use any service that hosts files to host your code)...

Therefore, I can only direct you to the following answers:

- [MobileFirst OAuth and Logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253465/mobilefirst-oauth-and-logout)
- [MobileFirst OAuth Logout, cached OAuth indentity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30276754/mobilefirst-oauth-logout-cached-oauth-indentity)